# Improving speed to find centre of tree?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

Made this code yesterday. What this code is supposed to do is to find in a graph, the node With the least Maximum distance between to all other nodes! For instance in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utEhl.jpg) example graph, 2 is the node that has the least Maximum distance to all other nodes. I found out that the complexity is O(n*(n*m)), and that Works great when I have less than 5000 nodes. What could I possibly fix to make this solution handle nodes >100 000? Should I use for instance iteration instead of recursion?

```
#include <cstudio>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
int biggest_dist(int n, int v, const vector< vector<int> >& graph)
{ //This function finds the diameter of thegraph
int INF = 2 * graph.size(); // Bigger than any other length
vector<int> dist(n, INF);

dist[v] = 0;
queue<int> next;
next.push(v);

int bdist = 0; //biggest distance
while (!next.empty()) {
    int pos = next.front();
    next.pop();
    bdist = dist[pos];

    for (int i = 0; i < graph[pos].size(); ++i) {
        int nghbr = graph[pos][i];
        if (dist[nghbr] > dist[pos] + 1) {
            dist[nghbr] = dist[pos] + 1;
            next.push(nghbr);
        }
    }
}

return bdist;
}


Will the solution be efficient enough to solve more than 100 000 R under 1sec?
```

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's about a code review and should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is much more an algorithmic review. My gut feeling is that dynamic problem is the solution -- there must be often, if not in the generic case, a lot of calculation shared between sub-graphs. The most trivial case being in calculating any metric first in the path from B->C and then from A->B->C.

Comment: I don't see anything in the CODE that may be optimized for your program to handle 100k nodes. If you want to handle this number of nodes in realtime, you will probably want to find another algorithm or modify current.

Comment: Can you add more details for your problem, especially about the graph. If the graph is unconnected, so what will be the result?

Comment: @Paul, I have added an answer on Quora.

Comment: You can use floyd-warshall algorithm to find distances between all two vertices in O(n^3) time. And after that find your vertex in O(n^2) time. Total cost is O(n^3) which might be better than your O(n^2 * m) BFS. However if you graph has a special form then there might exist a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a better, `O(n)` algorithm if your graph is a tree. I'm not aware of a better algorithm in the general case.

Compute the degree of each node. Remove all nodes with minimum degree (the leaf nodes initially) and update the degrees of their adjacent nodes (which will now become leaf nodes themselves). Do this until only one node remains (or two). That will be your answer.

Comment: If your graph is a tree, O(n+m) = O(n).

Comment: @JuanLopes I fixed it. The OP has linked to the original problem in a comment, which makes it clear that it's a tree, so I don't see why the -1.

Comment: The downvote isn't mine. I just commented.